# How do I force R to write out scientific notation with 3 significant figures after a decimal?

Tags: r, significant-digits

Because Fortran, I need to write a program that, among other wonderful features, will force R to output a number in scientific notation with 3 significant figures after the decimal point.

Specifically, I need 170.5 to be written to output as 1.705e+02.

Using options(scipen = -999), I can force r to write 170.5 as 1.71e+02. However, this is insufficient for my use - ireally need that third digit after the period.

I think this question ought to be easy, but I am unable to figure out how to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: Why does Fortran requirement a non significant digit?  Maybe you can explain why you have this need.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try

```
options(scipen = -999, digits = 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at either sprintf or formatC.

```
sprintf("%s", 170.5)
[1] "1.705e+02"

 print( sprintf("%s", 170.5), quote=FALSE)
[1] 1.705e+02
```